# Values between classes - null

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have to ask again.. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I have an "tree" for my files, which is working and displays me the folder of my drive.

Now I want to get the path of the selected folder with an listener and set/get-methods into another class.

My listener looks like:

```
TreeSelectionListener treeSelectionListener = new TreeSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent tse){
                DefaultMutableTreeNode node =
                    (DefaultMutableTreeNode)tse.getPath().getLastPathComponent();
                showChildren(node);
                setFileDetails((File)node.getUserObject());
                if(node != null)
                    //System.out.println("Test" + node);
                    setSelectedNode(NodeForMain); 
                    //NodeForMain = node;
                    //System.out.println("GetNode" + getSelectedNode());
            }
        };
```

And my get and set methods looks like:

```
 public void setSelectedNode(DefaultMutableTreeNode node) {

    NodeForMain = node; 
    //System.out.println("String:" + NodeForMain.toString());
    System.out.println("Set:" + NodeForMain);
}

public DefaultMutableTreeNode getSelectedNode() {
    System.out.println("Get"+ NodeForMain);
    return NodeForMain; 
}
```

So, if I am displaying the node with "system.out.println(..)" in the class of the tree, it displays me the right path.

But if I'am am going to display the path with get methods in the other class it display me "null".

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode node  = FileBrowser.getSelectedNode();
System.out.println("Knoten:" + node);
```

I don't know, what I am doing wrong.. Hope it's enough code to understand.

Comment: You'll probably need to create and post a valid [mcve] in order to get a decent answer, one not requiring a bit of guessing.

Comment: Shouldn't you call setSelectedNode(node);

Comment: @DanielJipa: Oh yes, that's true. But the output is the same..

Comment: Make sure it's the same object reference called in that other class.

Comment: That was the problem! Many thanks.

Comment: @DanielJipa made a good guess, but understand that that was all it was, since it is impossible to know that this was the cause of your problem based on what you've posted. In the future, please add a decent MCVE with your question, since with one of these, there would be no need to guess.